# Can Geany give me the character location of the text cursor?

Tags: cursor-position, geany

I'm on Mint, using Geany to program with a tool that will give me the line and column location of a code bug; but it won't go further than opening the file with Geany, I have to find it myself. That's all well and good, I like Geany; but it would be much easier if I could get the position of the cursor by line number and character, like the bug is being given to me, instead of line number and column number, which is, honestly, almost useless to me.

I cannot find any obvious way to do this in Geany's preferences.

Is there a way to get a readout, such as on the toolbar, of the exact *character index*, instead of *spacial index*, of the cursor location?

Thank you!